# command line argument to watchdog function

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, watchdog, python-watchdog

Below is a working python script which accepts a directory path via command line and watches that directory, spitting out the name of any new image file which appears in the directory.
I would like to add a second argument via command line which would end up feeding into the function which is called whenever the new image file appears in that directory.

```
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler


class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.jpg", "*.png", "*.tif"]

    # we only care about newly created images
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(event.src_path + "want to have arg2 available here") 


from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver as Observer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args[0] if args else '/images')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

This way when I call the file it can be like this:
`python myfile.py /path/to/images arg2`
and arg2 will be available in the on_created(self, event).
sorry so new to classes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the extra argument(s) in the instance of `MyHandler`, so that the `on_event` method can access them when it is called. Something like

```
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.jpg", "*.png", "*.tif"]

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.extra_args = args

    def on_created(self, event):
        print(event.src_path + extra_args[0])

 from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver as Observer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]    
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(*args[1:]), path=args[0] if args else '/images')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: python3 is required for this, which is fine, it just took me a while to set up. Now I get this error message:    ` print(event.src_path + extra_args[0])
NameError: name 'extra_args' is not defined`

Comment: oops! I think this is fixed by adding "self" here: print(event.src_path + self.extra_args[0])